# PHP Caching simplexml - Some RSS feeds not updating, but others are

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

We are using simplexml_load_file() to get an RSS feed of news stories.  The raw xml feed build date updates regularly, however if I use print_r to see the data of the feed while using simplexml_load_file(), the build date DOES NOT update as often as the raw feed.

For example right now the simplexml outputs this build date:

```
[lastBuildDate] => Tue, 23 May 2017 18:27:26 +0000
```

But the actual direct link to the xml says this:

```
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 24 May 2017 16:21:44 +0000</lastBuildDate>
```

...and we are missing data (stories from the feed) from the more recent build.

What is even stranger is that only some of the RSS feeds we are pulling have this behavior, although we load them the same way. A feed that originates at our server is fine, another from an external source is fine, but two coming from another external source are the culprits.

We are simply doing this:

```
 <?php
      $xml=simplexml_load_file("http://path/to/xml/file");
      print_r($xml);
    ?>
```

On every page load our goal is to have the MOST CURRENT data from the RSS feeds. We also put some cache-busting stuff in the header of the page (cache-control and pragma) but it isn't helping. What are we missing?

This is what we have installed: PHP Version 5.6.30 and Apache/2.2.15 (Unix).

Comment: Working fine for me https://eval.in/804559

Comment: Sahil - Maybe I wasn't too clear. For clarification - I'm not looking for a string. I have an actual RSS feed with actual build dates that change constantly. I need the most current and SimpleXML gives me data from feeds that were built hours ago.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a cacheing issue on the server level. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. SimpleXML and everything setup nicely. Some RSS Feed show, when refreshing, the new posts, some not...
I tried to set `header('Cache-Control: no-cache');` but that did not help either...
Any other idea. Using SimplePie is not really an option for me...

Answer (score 0):

There is some cacheing that happens somewhere with simple_xml_loadfile which is beyond my comprehension. Using SimplePie PHP feed parsing solved our issue because the handling of the cacheing is built into this tool.